# USB size shown is smaller than real size

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have used my USB key as bootable drive. But now, I am unable to use the key. Moreover, the size of the key shown is smaller than the real size of the key. Actually my key's size is 16 GB, but now, it is saying that it is only 8 MB. 
I have tried the following command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2048` so as to erase everything, but to no avail.

Partition table with `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 8 MiB, 8388608 bytes, 16384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Using Gparted, this is what I have.

[image]

Could anyone help to figure out what should I do?

Comment: Look like your USB key is dead. Not much to be done here.

Comment: Look at gparted. See what it says and try repartitioning if you can. Your USB drive might not be dead, but you should check first!

Comment: Try  `sudo fdisk -l` and see if it shows the correct size for the usb drive. If it shows the correct size then your usb should be ok.

Comment: I edited my question with output of  `fdisk` and `gparted`

Comment: It seems mikewhatever was correct, your drive appears to be dead. :( I don't know what to say, but mikewhatever is right again, there's nothing to be done here.

Comment: @rplaughlin, just have to throw it away :) !

Comment: It might be fun to use it as a tiny box for something... Anyway, I hope you're not too disappointed. I know I am.

Comment: It has been some years since I have been using this USB key... Anyway, thanks for the help!